# How to use AND/OR in if else PHP statement

Tags: php, if-statement

how to shorting the codes

```
if(stristr($A,'Erorr Email')){
    echo 'Error Login';
}

elseif(stristr($A,'Erorr Password')){
    echo 'Error Login';
}
```

i want add 'AND' to If and delete 'elseif' ..

Comment: Using AND makes it complicated. You would need a condition like `!(!stristr($A,'Erorr Email') && !stristr($A,'Erorr Password'))`. Use `stristr($A,'Erorr Email') || stristr($A,'Erorr Password')` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if(stristr($A,'Erorr Email') || stristr($A,'Erorr Password')){
     echo 'Error Login';
}
```

And read this link to learn more:
[PHP Operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php)

Answer (score 4):

If you use `AND` both the statements must be true i.e $A should be equal to `Erorr Email` and `Erorr Password` which is not correct and not possible.

You have to use `OR`. So that if any one of the statement is true then it enters into the loop.

```
if(stristr($A,'Erorr Email') || stristr($A,'Erorr Password')){
     echo 'Error Login';
}
```

or

```
if(stristr($A,'Erorr Email') or  stristr($A,'Erorr Password')){
     echo 'Error Login';
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php

Answer (score 2):

```
if(stristr($A,'Erorr Email') || (stristr($A,'Erorr Password')){
    echo 'Error Login';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

OR sample

```
if(stristr($A,'Erorr Email') || (stristr($A,'Erorr Password')){
    echo 'Error Login';
}
```

AND sample

```
if(!(!stristr($A,'Erorr Email') && !stristr($A,'Erorr Password'))){
    echo 'Error Login';
}
```